# `&mdash;` or `&#8212;` is there any difference in HTML output?

Tags: html, ascii

`&mdash;` or `&#8212;`

Is there a difference between these?  Is one better-supported than the other?

Comment: Just for completeness: the actual long dash ("mdash") character is: — and should be as wide as the character "m"

Comment: yes, a capital M

Answer (score 87, accepted):

SGML parsers (or XML parsers in the case of XHTML) can handle `&#8212;` without having to process the DTD (which doesn't matter to browsers as they just slurp tag soup), while `&mdash;` is easier for humans to read and write in the source code.

Personally, I would stick to a literal em-dash and ensure that my character encoding settings were consistent.

Answer (score 15):

`&mdash;` :: `&#8212;` :: `\u2014`

When representing the m-dash in a JavaScript text string for output to HTML, note that it will be represented by its unicode value. There are cases when ampersand characters ('&') will not be resolved—notably certain contexts within JSX. In this case, neither `&mdash;` nor `&#8212;` will work. Instead you need to use the Unicode escape sequence: `\u2014`.

For example, when implementing a `render()` method to output text from a JavaScript variable:

```
render() {
   let text='JSX transcoders will preserve the & character&mdash;to ' 
            + 'protect from possible script hacking and cross-site hacks.'
   return (
     <div>{text}</div>
   )
}
```

This will output:

```
<div>JSX transcoders will preserve the & character&mdash;to protect from possible script hacking and cross-site hacks.</div>
```

Instead of the `&`– prefixed representation, you should use \u2014:

```
let text='JSX transcoders will preserve the & character\u2014to …'
```

Comment: Works great with React.

Answer (score 13):

They are exactly the same character. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Barring browser bugs they will display the same in all cases, so the only difference would be concerning code readability, which would point to `&mdash;`.

Or, if you are using UTF-8 as a charset in your HTML document, you could enter the character directly. That would also display exactly the same.

Comment: Note that this only true for HTML, in XML, `&8212;` always works whereas `&mdash;` depends on having declared the entity.

Answer (score 2):

From W3 web site [Common HTML entities used for typography](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography)

> For the sake of portability, Unicode entity references should be reserved for use in documents certain to be written in the UTF-8 or UTF-16 character sets. In all other cases, the alphanumeric references should be used.

Translation: If you are looking for widest support, go with `&mdash;`

Answer (score 1):

Could be that using the numeral code is more universal, as it's a direct reference to a character in the html entity table, but I guess they both work everywhere. The first notation is just massively easier to remember for a lot of characters.