# Html Entity Name vs entity Number?

Tags: asp.net, html, html-entities

I saw this table  : [image]

when I program Asp.net and want to display these special html entities , I use Entity *Name*.

(but both seems to work)

question :

in what scenarios should I use entity **number** ( and **not** entity **name** ) ?

p.s. Ive seen situation in which asp.net doesnt like Entity *Number*

Comment: Same, without Asp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133766/mdash-or-8212-is-there-any-difference-in-html-output the framework probably does not make a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not clear guidance as to when one should use a [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) (say `&#163;`) over a [character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) (say `&pound;`) or vice versa.

So long as a character entity reference is a defined one (you can define your own), you can use it.

The converse is that if it isn't defined, you should use a numeric character reference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use either of them for most characters. Just enter the characters, in UTF-8, or in ISO-8859-1, whichever you are using. If you don’t know how to type a no-break space, for example, and don’t want to learn it, the entity reference `&nbsp;` and the character reference `&#160;` are equivalent, so use whichever you find less confusing. (The latter is *not* an entity reference, so “Entity Number” is a misnomer.)

Only for “<” and for “&”, when used as data characters, will you need “escape” notations, and for them, I cannot figure out any reason why you would use character references, instead of the reasonably mnemonic entity references `&lt;` and `&amp;`.